# Dynamically call method of class with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to call a method of a class dynamically in Typescript and I've got a compilation error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WasRun'.
  
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'WasRun'.
```

Here is the class:

```js
export class WasRun {
  wasRun = false;

  constructor(private methodName: string) {}

  testMethod() {
    this.wasRun = true;
  }

  run() {
    const { methodName } = this;

    if (typeof this[methodName] !== "function") {
      return;
    }

    this[methodName]();
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to do that the way you are trying.

`this[methodName]()` is wrong.

The typescript compiler and the javascript interpreter need a defined function to run your code. Even if typescript somehow compiles your code (which it will not, and should not), javascript surely will throw an error.

You will have to find another way to dynamically call your functions. Because the name you give to your functions is for your (the programmer's) reference. Once the interpreter takes over, it will have its own way to refer to a function. So, at runtime your function name doesn't really exist for the interpreter to figure out which function you want to call by the provided string.

You can do this: `if (methodName === 'abc') return abc()`. It will run perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the errro it seems like a type error you may need to assign wasRun as

```
  let wasRun:boolean = false;
```